# Edit the list in Standard view in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, share

I had a specific requirement and would like to know if anybody had an idea on how I should go ahead with this problem.

I have a custom list (with a custom form) and would like to edit/change entries in standard view itself. For example, I have a dropdown in the form where priority is entered. This is a dropdown (with options high, medium, low) and I would like to update the entry in the list without having to click the edit item button.

Hopefully, I have made myself as clear as possible.If there is anything else please let me know !!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't think its possible OOB with a standard view. But a datasheet view will do this without any customization work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datasheet view....

Or you can customize your standard view with JavaScript. For example when the user will move the mouse hover the priority then a dropdown will appear and the user can choose a value. After that it's quite easy to update the record from the page with JavaScript (see http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ or http://spservices.codeplex.com/)

But it means you need some advanced skills with JavaScript and HTML...

Comment: Any place where I can get a demo / understanding on how to add Javascript to create the dropdown when the user hovers over priority ?